# flutter return data from a screen error with pushNamed()

Tags: android, flutter

I use pushNamed() to get return data from screen like this:

```
_pushToPage2() async {
    String result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/page2");
    print("$tag $result");
}
```

But there was something wrong with the code, this the full error stack trace:

> E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>       type 'MaterialPageRoute' is not a subtype of type 'Route'
>       0      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1408:14)
>       1      NavigatorState.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1454:20)
>       2      _MyHomePageState._pushToPage2 (file:///Users/wang/flutter_project/flutter_navigation/lib/main.dart:113:50)
>       
>       3      _MyHomePageState.build. (file:///Users/wang/flutter_project/flutter_navigation/lib/main.dart:58:19)
>       4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
>       5      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
>       6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
>       7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
>       8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
>       9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
>       10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
>       11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
>       12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
>       13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
>       14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
>       15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
>       16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
>       17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:153:13)
>       18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:107:5)

But the following code is working properly:

```
_pushToPage2() async {
    String result = await Navigator.push(
         context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
    print("$tag $result");
}
```

Comment: Is your problem being solved now or you need some more help in this question?  Did my answer is useful and helped you to solved your problem?

Comment: I got the same question and as there is not really a answer that works I suppose its not supported to return something with NamedRoutes

Answer (score 16):

For me, the error was a different one (`type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<String>'`), and I solved it by declaring the returning value as a dynamic type:

```dart
dynamic result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page");
```

While this loses some type safety, it works fine for me.

Comment: In `/page`, how you return data back?

Comment: You can return data like `Navigator.pop(context, "any data");`

Comment: how do you handle a Data object? without serializing it to string and back.

Comment: @none You can pass back any object you want. It's not restricted to `String`.

Comment: I think this is a rather dirty solution as it does not respect type safety like you say. Please have a look at my solution instead!

Answer (score 8):

I have a same problem. And finally I found a solution. Cast your result to your type.

For example:

```dart
String result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/some_route")
```

The code above will raise the **exception**.

But, you can do like this:

```dart
final result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/some_route") as String;
```

The code above will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the working type `Page2` for `MaterialPageRoute` in the router

```dart
case "/page2":
  return MaterialPageRoute<Page2>(...};
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided answers seem to address your issue as they advice you to abandon type safety by using `dynamic` or `var`. This is a bad workaround.

If you intent to use `pushNamed` while maintaining static typing, which you seem to want as you are providing the type `String` for the variable you want to store the result in, there is only one possibility: type casting.

So instead of using `pushNamed()` as a [generic method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-generic-methods) like this:

```
_pushToPage2() async {
    String result = await Navigator.pushNamed<String>(context, "/page2");
    print("$tag $result");
}
```

you typecast the method result like this:

```
_pushToPage2() async {
    String result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/page2") as String;
    print("$tag $result");
}
```

Not being able to provide a type to the `pushNamed()` method is a known deficiency of `Navigator` in combination with `route tables`, as stated [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57186#issuecomment-728860342).

Answer (score -2):

In your main.dart file and inside your main Function define MaterialApp widget, and inside it we define routes (screens) of our App.

main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp( 
    new MaterialApp( 
      home: new Screen1(), 
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> { 
        '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(), 
        '/screen2' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen2() 
      },
    )
  );
}
```

Screen1:

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ...
      }
}
```

Screen2:

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ...
    }
}
```

And to Navigate to screens we do:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
```

`async` and `awiat` is not needed but if you are doing async programming for e.g; you are querying Firestore and on the basis of the result of query, you choose to navigate to the new screen or choose to show the error.

For more details: [routing and navigation in flutter](https://medium.com/@kpbird/flutter-introduction-of-routing-and-navigation-49738dbd6abe)

**Edit:**

To pass data between Screens, pass the argument to the Screen2 constructor and use `Navigator.push()`. Remember that in `Navigator.pushNamed()` you pass context and route name only, and you can't pass arguments in it.

```
 Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(new Color(0xFF66BB6A)),
            ));
```

Screen2:

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
     Screen2(this.color);
     final Color color;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           ...
        }
 }
```

Comment: How can the data be sent back to the parent screen? I didn't see anything like that in your code. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are passing the data using `push()` not `pushNamed()` Please read the question carefully

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I have answered about it that we can't pass argument or data from pushNamed()

Comment: So, your answer could have been just one line in the beginning that you can't do that, sorry !

Comment: @CopsOnRoad well , i also see that OP asked about getting data back from the child screen, which i show in my answer

Comment: You answer misses the point. OP asked how to return data from `pushNamed()`. Nowhere in you explanations I see you working with a return value. Instead you cover a completely different topic: how to pass arguments.